# sending jtable selected rows to servlet all at once

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, jquery-jtable

I have to send selected rows in jtable to servlet to read the values and display them all in another jtable.But the problem is if i select multiple rows it is sending these rows to servlet in differennt request so i can use only columns of one row at a time,but i want all the rows to be used at a time in servlet.The code i have written is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
        title : 'Selected Table metadata',
        selecting : true, 
        multiselect : true, 
        selectingCheckboxes : true, 
        actions : {
            listAction : 'meta?action=list',
        },
        fields : {
            columnname : {
                title : 'COLUMN NAME',
                key : true,
                width : '40%',
                list : true,
                create : true
            },
            datatype : {
                title : 'DATA TYPE',
                width : '40%',
                edit : false
            },
            columnlength : {
                title : 'LENGTH',
                width : '40%',
                edit : true
            }
        }
        ,
        selectionChanged: function () {
            var $selectedRows = $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
            $selectedRows.each(function () {

                var record = $(this).data('record');
                var columnname = record.columnname;
                var datatype = record.datatype;
                var columnlength = record.columnlength;


                $.get('meta?action=dataload', {
                    columnname : columnname,datatype:datatype,columnlength:columnlength
            }, function(response) {


            });


            });
        }

    });
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
```

and to servlet it is sending one one request for each selection,but i want all the rows to be send to
servlet in a single request , if not possible i will give a button in jsp as "send" then this request will carry all selected rows...

Answer (score 0):

By handling the selectionChanged event, wouldn't you be sending all of the rows on every row selection/deselection operation done by the user?

I do it like this, via a button click in my case, but i guess you could call the same function from the selectionChanged event handler

```
function sendSelectedRows(){

  var selectedRows = $('#tableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');

  selectedRows.each(function(){
    var record = $(this).data('record');
    selectedRowsData.push(record);
  });

myjsonpost("someserversidepage.php?; ?>",encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(selectedRowsData)));

}

function myjsonpost(path, params, method) {
  method = method || "post"; 

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", method);
  form.setAttribute("action", path);

  var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Record");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params);
  form.appendChild(hiddenField);

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

hope it helps.